# Subscripts in partial derivatives

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I would like to print the partial derivative operator `$\frac{\partial}{\partial k_x}$`, but the spacing and the length of the bar bug me a little. I would really like the fraction to be typeset as `$\frac{\partial}{\partial k}$` (which has a shorter bar and the upper `$\partial$` further to the left), with the subscript `${}_x$` added afterwards.

I'm definitely sure this is possible. What would be the quickest, cleanest way?

Answer (score 9):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


1 $\frac{\partial}{\partial k}$

2 $\frac{\partial}{\partial k_x}$


3 $\frac{\partial}{\partial k}_{\scriptscriptstyle x}$

4 $\frac{\partial}{\partial k_{\rlap{$\scriptscriptstyle x$}}}$


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution 4 does what the OP wants, but it has the same drawback (mentioned by Matthew Leingang) as A. Ellett's answer.

Comment: yes true any version that hides the width inside the frac ought to add some white space after the frac to compensate.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that works with `\mathrlap` from the `mathtools` package, combined with a `\phantom` to get proper spacing *after* the derivative. (It's not so efficient since I nested `\mathrlap`.)

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*\xpartial[2]{%
  \mathrlap{\frac{\partial}{\partial #1_{\mathrlap{#2}}}}%
  \phantom{\frac{\partial}{\partial #1_{#2}}}%
  }
\begin{document}
$\frac{\partial}{\partial k_x} g$ versus $\xpartial{k}{x} g$
\end{document}
```

(By the way, I would have expected `x_k`, not `k_x` in the denominator.)

Comment: The derivative is with respect to the $x$ component of a wave vector $\mathbf{k}$.

Answer (score 4):

Using `mathtools` there is `\mathmakebox` which behaves much like `\makebox` but is sensitive to the mathematical context and will set things correctly:

Or as @Qrrbrbirlbel suggested, you can use `\mathrlap` and its ilk.  I illustrate both `\mathmakebox` and `\mathllap` here  (I've never like the way the numerator and denominator are off set when you want a negative in the numerator).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \frac{\partial}{\partial k_{\mathmakebox[0pt][l]{x}}}
    \]


    \[
        \frac{\mathllap{-}1}{2}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I like about `\mathmakebox` is that it allows you define the width of the box and the positioning.  Probably for your purposes, `\mathrlap` is all you need.

Comment: Hint: `\mathrlap`

Comment: But the subscripted x now crashes into whatever would follow this symbol.  Consider `\frac{\partial}{\partial k_{\mathmakebox[0pt][l]{x}}}\frac{k_x}{k_x + k_y}`.  Maybe you should add a `\phantom{\scriptstyle x}`?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang indeed.  I was a bit hasty and neglected to think of the spacing issue.

Comment: Should have said `\scriptscriptstyle x`, sorry.

Comment: why to load both `amsmath` and `mathtools`?

Answer (score 1):

Bingo! Got it. Some negative space does it: `$\frac{\partial}{\partial k_x\!\!\!}\,$`

Comment: No, in all honesty, you did not get it: Using `\!\!\!` and `\,` just "almost next to each other" shows that something is wrong.

Comment: @tohecz: The only problems I see here is that 1. one has to guess the spacing and 2. the positive spacing with `\,` is too small so that one can have an overlap. The `\!` and `\,` are only _almost_ next to each other, and this makes a lot of sense.