# Nicer alignment of x^*/2

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, fractions

I'm trying to typeset `$\frac{x^*}{2}$`, but I can't find a (simple) way to make the alignment look nice. So far, I've tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^*}{2} \qquad \frac{x^*}{2\phantom{{}^*}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

With the following output:

[image: alignment issues]

In the left one, it looks odd because the `x` is very off-center, and in the right example the fraction bar is extended way more to the right than what's really necessary.

Is there a nicer (and still simple enough) way to typeset this fraction?

Comment: The left hand side version is correct.

Comment: @egreg: I still think it looks odd - perhaps even more so in inline fractions (i.e. `$\frac{x^*}{2}$`).

Comment: I would definitely write $x^{*}/2$.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: I think your link is broken (at least it points to a topic that's not even vaguely related...). Would you mind double-checking?

Comment: Strongly related [Subscripts in partial derivatives](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98770).

Answer (score 18):

```
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x^*}{2} \quad \frac{x^*}{2\phantom{{}^*}} \quad
\frac{x\rlap{$^*$}}{\,2\,}
\end{equation*}
```

The correct one is the first one, as the ugly syntax of the other two demonstrates :-) However, I have to admit that the third one is the best looking one:

[image: Result]

## Update

As egreg noted in a comment, the problem with the third solution is that it is not clear if the * applies only to x, or to the whole fraction. Thiking about this, I've found another solution which avoids this problem, has a cleaner syntax, and still (imho) looks better than the first one.

The following MWE shows first the standard way, second my first attempt, and third my new proposed solution. I put them in the context of a bigger expression, and aligned them vertically at the right bar, for easier comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Big|\frac{x^*}{2}               \Big|&=y \\
\Big|\frac{x\rlap{$^*$}}{\,2\,}  \Big|&=y \\
\Big|\frac{x^*\!}{2}             \Big|&=y
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about `\rlap` :)

Comment: Did you try adding a symbol after `\frac{x\rlap{$^*$}}{\,2\,}`? It will be pushed below the asterisk. I'm still convinced that `\frac{x^*}{2}` is the best: with your `\rlap` (by the way `\mathrlap` from `mathtools` should be used) it's ambiguous whether the asterisk applies to x or to the whole fraction.

Answer (score 10):

How about using `\mathrlap` from the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)-package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^*}{2} \qquad \frac{x^*}{2\phantom{{}^*}} \qquad \frac{x^{\mathrlap{*}}}{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This inserts the asterisk without adding additional space and thus keeping the fraction line as long as in the first example:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The `\mathrlap` suggestion has the same drawback as egreg explains in [his comment to JLDiaz' answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100326/nicer-alignment-of-x-2#comment217144_100327).

Answer (score 3):

Aligning things that should not be aligned is a bad idea. Very similar example to yours is adding `\phantom{-}` in front of `0` and `1` in matricis comprising only `0`, `1` and `-1`. You align the numbers, but you lose the visual distinction between `1` and `-1`.

Here, it is a bit different but still valid: I, as a reader, would really get the impression that there's a missing symbol after `2`, just because the whole denominator is not centered, whereas I expect it to be centered.

Conclusion: Two options are correct: `\frac{x^*}{2}` and `x^*/2`.

Comment: Today, we are fated to disagree about phantom minus signs :)  I right-align all my matrices by default, specifically for this purpose.

Comment: TBH, I can't say I don't consider it nicer looking, I just have the bad readability experience.

Comment: @RyanReich -- matrices aren't fractions.  for matrices, aligning so that the numerical value of comparable elements is parallel is appropriate, and there, the phantom minus sign or right-alignment (in the absence of non-matching decimal places) is the proper thing to do.  likewise for tabular material.